# class object create with using in c#

Tags: c#, class

Create class MustDispose.cs

```
public class MustDispose
{
    public MustDispose()
    {

    }
}
```

in.aspx Page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        using (MustDispose obj = new MustDispose) 
        {
          // use the object
        }
    }
```

errorr

> Destructors and object.Finalize cannot be called directly. Consider
>   calling IDisposable.Dispose if available.

Comment: Question is not clear but I assume the problem is that you've not implemented `IDisposable` so `using()` cant access `Dispose()`

Comment: Surely you could have figured this out if you just spent 5 minutes researching this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You class has to impplement `IDisposable`, in oder to be used inside `using` statement.

Example:

```
public class MustDispose : IDisposable
{
    public MustDispose()
    {

    }

    //implement Dispose
    public void Dispose() 
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

reading from [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of
>   IDisposable objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `IDisposable` like so:

```
class TestDispose : IDisposable
{
    public TestDispose() 
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // dispose of your resources here
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to use it in a `using` block which automatically calls `obj.Dispose` at the end of the block.

```
using (var obj = new TestDispose())
{
    ...
}
```

Is like:

```
var obj = new TestDispose();

try
{

    ...
}
finally
{
    obj.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: `using` is not quite equal to just calling `Dispose`. What would happen if an exception was thrown after you created `obj` in your description?

Comment: Good catch, updated it to be a more accurate representation. Would you agree?